# Kafka-python retrieve the list of topics

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm using **[kafka-python](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.2/)** and I'm wondering if there is a way for showing all the topics.

Something like this:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Comment: did you try with http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.2/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.topics ?

Comment: Many thanks, is what i was looking for. If you want to write an answer I will mark it as correct. Maybe could be useful also for others.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
import kafka
consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(group_id='test', bootstrap_servers=['server'])
consumer.topics()
```

Comment: Sounds good, doesn't work

"ValueError: Topic name "*" is illegal, it contains a character other than ASCII alphanumerics, ".", "_" and "-""

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `KafkaAdminClient`, not `KafkaConsumer`:

```
import kafka
admin_client = kafka.KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=['server'])
admin_client.list_topics()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the method [KafkaConsumer.topics()](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.2/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.topics).

Comment: This does not seem to poll Kafka for the available topics, only lists the topics that a consumer instance is subscribed to.

Comment: This is not a static method, so must create an instance of KafkaConsumer to use it, but it turns out you can do that without a topic list, and it will in fact list the topics from kafka