# Why do I get an empty last line when using os.popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, apache-kafka

I am using this Python (Python 3) code, in order to get the list of all topics

as:

```
more test.py

list = os.popen(" kafka-topics.sh –zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --list | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'  ").read().split('\n')
print (list)
```

When I run the python script, I noticed that last line is like the following

```
…………………………………………………………
……….'topic32', 'topic33', 'topic34 , ‘ ‘]
```

So the last word is actually null because between the single quote as `‘ ‘` we do not have topic name

It's strange because in line I am using the sed - `sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`, in order to delete empty lines, and indeed not empty lines when I just run the following

```
kafka-topics.sh –zookeeperzoo_server:2181 --list | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

Any hint what is wrong with my Python line?

For example, when I run

```
kafka-topics.sh –zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --list | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

topic1
topic2
topic3
.
.
.
```

Comment: All valid UNIX text lines end with `'\n'`. Unlike on Windows where CRLF is a _separator_, on UNIX, CR is a line _terminator_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy to be precise, LF ("line feed", `\n`) is the terminator on Unix, and CR ("carriage return", `\r`) is typically not present.

Comment: @poolie, I believe you're repeating what I already said in my initial comment. When I referenced CRLF, I very explicitly said "on Windows". The important point being made is that the platform distinction is not just between LF and CRLF, but also separator-vs-terminator; so it's important for folks to keep _both_ differences in mind (that on UNIX, having a line terminator at the end of a text file is 100% normal, expected, and even _required_ for it to be a legal text file). I assume that the OP comes from the Windows world, and came to expect it to be a separator vs a terminator there.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to say. On Unix there are normally no CR characters at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with `popen`. The string that `read` returns ends with a linefeed.

```
>>> "foo\nbar\n".split()
['foo', 'bar', '']
```

If you don't want the empty string that follows the last linefeed, you should strip the final linefeed first.

```
list = os.popen(...).read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am using this Python (Python 3) code, in order to get the list of all topics

Why dont you use a python [kafka client](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-python/current/overview.html) and call [list topics](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Producer.list_topics) ?

Comment: first we are using Apace Kafka , second , the example that I gives described pure python conflicts , and actually I run   the kafka cli in order to get all topics names and to set them to variable , it will be useful , if you can gives example how to use the kafka client in way that I can use it in my python script

Comment: @jessica there is a link to the API call that should be done (see my answer). Look here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641755/kafka-python-retrieve-the-list-of-topics

Comment: In my eyes this is the way to go  so this is why I consider it as an answer.

Comment: @jessica Confluent Platform **includes Apache Kafka**, there is no difference. `kafka-python` library also has a list topics method if you have something against using `confluent-kafka-python` library